# Python3, range(a,b) function behaviour and empty lists

Tags: python-3.x, range

I am a bit confused about the behavior of the range() function in a specific use case.

When I was testing some code I wrote using nested FOR loops, in some cases, the statements in certain loops never seemed to execute at all.  I eventually realized that I was in some cases feeding a range() call with an input like:

`range(i,2)  # where i is 2, giving range(2,2)`

...which threw no error, but apparently never executed the for loop contents.  After some reading on Python3's FOR implementation, I then added "else:" statements to my loop:

```
for i in range(a,b):  # where a=b, i.e. range(2,2)
    [skipped code]
else:
    [other code]
```

...and the else-case code executed fine, as I guess all possible iterators for the given range values were (already) exhausted, and the for-else case was triggered as it's designed to be when that happens.

From what I can see in the documentation for range(), I found: "A range object will be empty if r[0] does not meet the value constraint."  ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range ).  I'm not quite sure what the "value constraint" is in this case, but if I'm understanding right, "range(a,b)" will return an empty list if a >= b.

My question is, is my understanding correct about when range() returns []?  Also, are there any other kinds of input cases where range(a,b) returns [], or other obscure edge case behaviors I should be aware of?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***range(n)*** generates an iterator to progress the integer numbers ***starting with 0 and ending with (n-1)***.

With reference to your FOR loop, it was not executed because the ending number (i.e. n - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1) is less than the starting number, 2. Since the step argument is omitted in your FOR loop, it defaults to 1. The step can be both negative and positive, but not zero.

**Syntax:**
    range(begin, end[, step])

**Examples:**
Both examples below will produce empty list.

- list(range(0))
- list(range(2,2))

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the overview and examples, that helps clarify the behavior pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see in [this](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) documentation, when you use `range(a,b)` you're setting its start and stop parameters.

what you need to know is that stop parameter is always excluded just like in lists slicing.

another remark is that you can set the `step`, so if you set a negative step you can actually use `a >= b`  like in this case:

```
range(10,4,-1)
```

Also please notice that all parameters need to be integers.

I recommend you visit the documentation provided above it's quite helpful.

Comment: That's a better documentation reference than I was able to find when I was searching, thank you!  That does look helpful.